# Styling Google Earth Plugin borders layer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth-plugin

I have my map, in 3d and I want to style it so that only counties with markers have a certain color. I also want to change the boundary color. I am using v3 of the Google Maps Api to load the earth. Is there a way to customize the map (3d) and also change the color of the borders in the in-built layer.

[Example 3d map](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/helloearth/index.html)

Comment: I am using google earth. The one that rotates the whole globe. Its not a flat map but a 3D representation of the globe.

Answer (score 1):

The borders layer you refer to is simply on or off, there are no methods to style it or alter its behaviour.

If you wish to have a custom data layer to show borders then you must construct it using KML.

You can obtain the data freely for this (country borders) any one of these links should help.

http://www.gelib.com/world-borders.htm

http://groups.google.com/group/kml-support/attach/031c560231ceefef/41300-WorldBorders.kmz?part=2

http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=56571#Post56571