# Select border of district, or country on google maps

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to select county, or district like Google Maps do on http://maps.google.com/.
I mean something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do it by Google Maps API? Is it possible to select more districts?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding) and [Google Maps Overview](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#RemovingOverlays)

You can try with [statesobj.js](http://mapscripting.com/examples/overlays/statesobj.js) for borders

Comment: yes, but I need to select non US districts, and I would like to use Google data which fits prefectly to the borders already displayed (doted one).

Comment: It would have helped to have said that in the question instead of demonstrating a single US state. You can only draw a border if you have the data. There is at least one [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312347/styling-google-earth-plugin-borders-layer).

Answer (score 0):

Google has started highlighting search areas in pick color.

It's not available in the API.

(It may be available in the future. Features of Google Maps do migrate into the API, but Google don't make announcements in advance)

You would need to find the city boundaries and draw the line yourself, through overlays.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using GEOJSON file.

My JS:

```
function initMap2() {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 13,
                mapId: "", // add map id here
                center: {lat: 41.015137, lng: 28.979530},
                //center: { lat: 20.773, lng: -156.01 },

            });
            map.data.loadGeoJson(
                "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ozanyerli/istanbul-districts-geojson/main/istanbul-districts.json"
            );

            map.data.setStyle({
                fillColor: '#810FCB',
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            });


        }
```

and I get the JSON data for Istanbul by using the following JSON:
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ozanyerli/istanbul-districts-geojson/main/istanbul-districts.json`